# Magento 2 - How can I change product visibility value using plugin afterSave or beforeSave method?

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade, plugin, visibility

I have created a plugin and I want to change product visibility value on product save but it's not working.

ProductAfterSave.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class ProductAfterSave {

    public function afterSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $product)
    {
        $productModel = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action');
        $productModel->setVisiblity(2);
        $productModel->save();

        return $product;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a before plugin like the below: I used the constante *Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG* for visibility but of course you can use the value 2.

If you are in trouble, I'll put my code online for you to check out a ful working version. good luck

```
class ProductBeforeSave {

    public function beforeBeforeSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $product->setVisibility(Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Herve, Can you please help me for a issue ? 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240448/magento-2-how-to-remove-unset-all-categories-from-a-product-using-plugin

Comment: Thanks Herve you're my hero

Comment: And you are mine Javier, hope you are keeping well!