# Magento 2 - How to remove/unset all categories from a product using plugin?

Tags: product, category, magento2.2, plugin, delete

I am trying to remove/unset all categories from a product using below code. It's working with Magento 2.1 but not with Magento 2.2.

How can we do this?

**app/code/Vender/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<plugin name="Vender-Module-product-model" type="Vender\Module\Plugin\TestPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
```

**app/code/Vender/Module/Plugin/TestPlugin.php**

```
namespace Vender\Module\Plugin;

class TestPlugin    
{ 
    public function beforeSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)   
    {
        $product->setCategoryIds("1");
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: beforeSave method comes from where ? Is it of the modal class of product ?

Comment: I have created a plugin for this.

app/code/Vender/Module/etc/di.xmldi.xml

<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
   <plugin name="Vender-Module-product-model" type="Vender\Module\Plugin\TestPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
</type>

app/code/Vender/Module/Plugin/TestPlugin.php

class TestPlugin
{ 
 public function beforeSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    { 
  $product->setCategoryIds("1");   
 }  
}

Comment: include this code in your question.

Comment: Already included

Answer (score 0):

If it was working fine with 2.1 and not working on 2.2. I suggest you to using factory class of product class.

```
public function beforeSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product)
{
  $prod = $product->create()->load(<product id>);
  $prod->setCategoryIds("1");  
 // $prod->save();
  $prod->getResource()->save();      
}
```

It is recommended to use factory class.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it does not work.

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: Page loading continuously and showing error "This page isn’t working"

Comment: ohhhhh ok i faced this kind of problem. See your method it's beforeSave. When you enter this method and call save method, then it will call again beforeSave method. 
It's like recursion

Comment: I modified my ans please check

Comment: It's not working, same issue.

Comment: Just comment the $prod->getResource()->save();   and check what error is coming.

Comment: Still having same issue